# ios UIScrollView image zoom changes after UINavigationController change

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming

I have a app with a UINavigationController changing out view controllers. Each of these view controllers has a UIScrollView with a UIImageView set up for zooming. However, on going back, sometimes the previous view controller will show the image highly zoomed in; and not where it was previous to pushing the new controller. In my view controller's -viewWillAppear method, I am setting the zoomScale to be the ratio of the scroll view's frame width to it's content width. How can I get the zoom level to at least go back to the default when popping the view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make your pop run a function first that stores you values you want after the pop into the `NSDictionary`, then you retrieve this in your viewDidLoad of the original view controller.

Then use your retrieve data to display the image at whatever state you want.

For links on NSDictionary tutorials look [at this site](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/nslog/nslogndictionary.html) and [this youtubeVideo.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=On_6fC9ZFDw)